# Convert a Perl function to PHP

Tags: php, perl, function, base32

I want to convert the perl function below to PHP function, if someone could help a little bit I'd appreaciate it:

```
sub encode32
{
    $_=shift;
    my($l,$e);
    $_=unpack('B*',$_);
    s/(.....)/000$1/g;
    $l=length;
    if($l & 7)
    {
        $e=substr($_,$l & ~7);
        $_=substr($_,0,$l & ~7);
        $_.="000$e" . '0' x (5-length $e);
    }
    $_=pack('B*', $_);
    tr|\0-\37|A-Z2-7|;
    lc($_);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty much everything there has a PHP equivalent. Why not give it a try and then ask for help with the specific bit you're stuck on?

Comment: ouch, assignment to an unlocalized `$_`, that's just a bug waiting to explode

Comment: I rather like the use of $1 and $l in the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a homegrown implementation of the Base32 encoding from [RFC 3548](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3548.html). A PHP implementation distributed under the terms of the GPL is available at [Fremnet](http://fremnet.net/article/215/class-base32).

Example use:

```
<?
include('class.base32.php5');

function encode32($str) {
  $b = new Base32(Base32::csRFC3548);
  return strtolower($b->fromString($str));
}

print encode32("foo bar baz quux") . "\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
mzxw6idcmfzcaytbpiqhc5lvpa
```